# login_required decorator in Django doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

I'm working on a Django(1.10) project in which I need to load a template only for logged in users, which is coming from profile template.I need to load **generateCert.html** only for logged in user, this template should display the same navbar as profile template because both of these templates have the same header.

**Here's my generateCert.html template:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load mathfilters %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>NAMI Montana | User's Dashboard</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content="http://webthemez.com"/>
<!-- css -->
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="{% static 'css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/flexslider.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<!--Pulling Awesome Font -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><![endif]-->
<style>
    input[type="image"] {
        padding-left: 30%;
        padding-top: 5%;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #fff;
        background: transparent;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 70%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="pull-left hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>matt@namimt.org </span></p>
                <p class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Tel No. (406) 443-7871</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- start header -->
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="logo"
                                                                     width="190px" height="50px;"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:signup' %}">SignUp</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'users:profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- end header -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top: 5%">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4> You have to pay <b> $95 </b> to generate your certificate.</h4>
                </div>
                {% block content %}
                    {{ form.render }}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

**Here are my views.py:**

```
@login_required
def payment_process(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    minutes = int(request.user.tagging.count()) * 5
    testhours = minutes / 60
    hours = str(round(testhours, 3))
    # pdb.set_trace()
    # What you want the button to do.
    invoice = generate_cid()
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "item_name": "Certificate of Completion from Nami Montana",
        "custom": {"name": str(request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name),
                   "hours": str(hours)},
        "invoice": str(invoice),
        "amount": "5.00",
        "notify_url": "https://8bf57d43.ngrok.io/users/paypal/",
        # "return_url": "https://b906ef46.ngrok.io/users/profile/",
        "cancel_return": "https://8bf57d43.ngrok.io/users/cancel/",
    }
    print(paypal_dict)
    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render_to_response("users/generateCert.html", context)
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/login')
```

**Here is my urls.py:**

```
   url('^process/$', views.payment_process, name='payment'),
```

> **generateCert.html** template display the menu of Anonymous users not logged in users menu, that means this template loaded by the unauthenticated user. How can I strict this template to only logged in users as it's coming from the profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that at all. What it does mean is that you are not passing the user to the template. This is because you are using `render_to_response` - which apart from anything else is deprecated - rather than the `render` shortcut which runs context processors.

Note, your `login_required` decorator makes that `if request.user.is_authenticated()` check pointless; the user will never not be authenticated.

Also note that you really should be using template inheritance to break out things like the top nav and the HTML boilerplate into their own templates.

Comment: how can I pass the `user` to `render_to_response`?

Comment: You could pass it like any other context object. But *don't*, use `render()` instead.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Django-PayPal module which required to send the form via `render_to_response` if I render it through `render` it will throw an error. That's why I need to send it via `render_to_reponse`.

Comment: No it doesn't, and no you don't. In fact, the django-paypal docs themselves [show the use of `render()`](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html). If you're getting an error, that means you have bugs somewhere else. Post the errors.

Comment: Here's when i user `render` :      `TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/process/

{'form': <PayPalPaymentsForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(cmd;charset;currency_code;no_shipping;business;item_name;custom;invoice;amount;notify_url;cancel_return)>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: abdul>>}`

Comment: Please look at the docs I linked to, or the Django docs themselves, for the syntax for `render`; it is `render(request, template_name, context)`.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, can you take a look at this question? please!                                    https://stackoverflow.com/q/49197631/7644562